# Substitute CarriageReturn with new line and pattern in VIM

Tags: bash, vim, awk, sed

I have a file.txt having three lines

```
line1
line2
line3
```

While i open file.txt in vim 
i want to substitute every CR(carriage Return) with a new line having the string "foo" , some thing like this.

```
$ cat file.txt
line1
foo
line2
foo
line3
foo
```

Also looking for the possibility with awk, sed and any thing else in bash script.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, if you just want to replace carriage return with `foo` :

```
sed 's/\x0D$/\nfoo/' file.txt
```

To add a line with string `foo` after every line :

```
sed 's/$/&\nfoo/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this substitution in Vim:

```
:%s/\n/&foo&
```

Or this macro:

```
:%g/^/norm ofoo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $0 "\nfoo"}' file
line1
foo
line2
foo
line3
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will do what you wanted in vim.

```
   :%s/\n/^Mfoo^M/g
```

To insert `^M` in the pattern, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
 `^M` inserts a newline whereas  in the pattern will literally insert `<`,`C`,`R` and `>`

Instead of `^M`, you can use `\r` for Linux machines.

```
    :%s/\n/\rfoo\r/g
```